# Python program outputting different results, even though no random is used

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve [Project Euler Problem 19](https://projecteuler.net/problem=19).

I am not here to ask for the answer to the problem, but I noticed that every time my program runs, its output is different.

Please can someone explain why for me

```
"""
    Author: Luke Spademan
    Calculates answer to project euler problem id19
    https://projecteuler.net/problem=19
"""


def calculate():
    ans = 0
    months = {
        "jan": 31,
        "feb": 28,
        "mar": 31,
        "apr": 30,
        "may": 31,
        "jun": 30,
        "jul": 31,
        "aug": 31,
        "sep": 30,
        "oct": 31,
        "nov": 30,
        "dec": 31,
    }
    i = 1
    for year in range(1901, 2001):
        for month in months:
            months["feb"] = 28
            if year % 4 == 0 and not (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0):
                months["feb"] = 29
            if i % 7 == 0:
                ans += 1
            i += months[month]
    return ans

if __name__ == "__main__":
    answer = calculate()
    print(answer)
```

Comment: Running it with Python 2 produces same output every time, running it with Python 3 doesn't... Strange

Comment: Is that to do with a bug in python3, or my badly written code?

Comment: I get 172 with python3 all the time, cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: what version. I am running python 3.4.3

Comment: my version is the same, 3.4.3

Comment: I am getting the same answer every time when I run it in the command line, but when run in pycharm I get different answers. Strange

Comment: Ran it with Python 3.6.1 64 Bit, I always get 172. (3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)])

Comment: It looks like it might be an issue with pycharm.

Comment: Running it with Python 3.5.2 gives different results every time. I get results between 169 and 175 (3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)])

Comment: I was running from command line and it was different

Comment: Also, you need to start with `i = 2`.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the result of the computation depends on the order in which `months` is iterated. As of Python 3.3, string hashing is randomized by default, meaning that this order will not be deterministic ([until Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46034339/python-program-outputing-different-results-even-though-no-random-is-used/46034612#comment79029178_46034612)). You can read about how to make this program run deterministically [here](https://jimmycallin.github.io/2016/01/03/make-your-python3-code-reproducible/), although I think that your intention is to iterate `months` in a predefined order always, in which case it should probably be a `list` or an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: It might be worth noting that Python 3.6 introduced a new dictionary implementation, which preserves order like an `OrderedDict` does. That behavior is considered an implementation detail for now (outside of a few specific cases like `**kwargs`), but it may become the official standard behavior in some future release.

Comment: confirmed that python3.6 gives the same answer everytime. Thankyou.

Comment: Note that it's not the only problem with OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

## With datetime

Before you get lost in implementation details about `dict`s and `OrderedDict`s, you could use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) to know what the answer should be:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> sum(1 for month in range(1,13) for year in range(1901, 2001) if date(year, month, 1).weekday() == 6)
171
```

## With list of tuples

Note that even with Python 3.6 or Python2 + OrderedDict, your code returns 172.

Your sunday test is written as `i % 7 == 0`. It means that the 1st day in your loop (1st of january 1901), which is a [tuesday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_1901#January_1.2C_1901_.28Tuesday.29), should be initialized with `i = 2`.

To avoid any problem with unsorted dicts, you could simply use a list of tuples :

```
def calculate():
    ans = 0
    months = [('jan', 31), ('feb', 28), ('mar', 31), ('apr', 30), ('may', 31), ('jun', 30), ('jul', 31), ('aug', 31), ('sep', 30), ('oct', 31), ('nov', 30), ('dec', 31)]
    i = 2
    for year in range(1901, 2001):
        for month_name, days in months:
            if month_name == "feb":
              if year % 4 == 0 and not (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0):
                  days = 29
              else:
                  days = 28
            if i % 7 == 0:
                ans += 1
            i += days
    return ans

if __name__ == "__main__":
    answer = calculate()
    print(answer)
```

This code returns `171` with any Python version.